# ASP.NET MVC 4 multilingual web template

Tags: multilingual

I'm thinking about making a multilingual website that supports arabic, english and some more languages. Does anyone know where to download or buy ASP.NET MVC 4 multilingual web template?

Comment: try to look for cms systems

Comment: thanks for your comment. I tried several mvc system. However when looking for mvc 4 very few are left to chose from, if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this page and save your money :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526827/MVC-Basic-Site-Step-1-Multilingual-Site-Skeleton

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. However I have already talked to the guy who made this article. It does not contain SEO oriented urls. Maybe he will update the article in the future. According to my "investigation" right now Septemper 2013, there is basically no article on the internet about MVC 4 multilingual Web site with SEO oriented urls.